# How to control /manage the mind when angry and lustful thoughts attack you very badly?

Tags: spirituality, mind

Our life is not constant some times go up and sometimes down

In our day to day life  sometimes  lust thought/anger thought  attack you but not badly , but at some special day lustful thought/anger thought  attack u very  badly at that moment our mind doesn't work properly , so we lose ourself when  we have done bad deed/work through lust/anger

my question is that How to control /manage the mind when lustful thought/anger thought attack you badly and badly ?

Comment: i think i gave this advice the last time you asked a similar question : go on a fruits-only diet for 2 days.

Comment: @mar   mmm  ya.. actually  this post is old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anger is the negative emotion that hits the mind and body badly. To overcome the strong emotions, you have to do work on your mind thoughts lets reduce the frequency of thoughts through pranayama as adhi is the invitation of certain diseases.
**[Yoga that helps to reduce mind fluctuations and relax. Here we work on our Manomaya Kosha](https://yogicank.com/yoga-helps-improve-mental-health-in-wfh-days/)**:-
Sit comfortably and practice conscious breathing, inhale, and exhale five to ten times. In conscious breathing, a person concentrates on a breathing pattern, inhales and bulges out the stomach like a balloon, and squeezes the stomach during exhale.

Practice Pranayama like anulom vilom, kapalabhati, and bhramari.

Practice meditation at least for 5 minutes and chanting OM. When you are peaceful from the inside, you will be treated the same way others.

Practice forward bending asanas like balasana, paschimottanasana; the spiritual significance of these asanas is bow down, which teaches us to become humble and egoless.

Thanks

Comment: Visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500). Don't quote your own link or advertize your own site

Answer (score 1):

This is not really very related to hinduism. It has more to do with psychology. However, a sattvik lifestyle can help eliminate such thoughts. For eg., vegetarian food, becoming an early waker, etc. From a science point of view one must always have good sleep and exercise. You can in addition practice yoga, meditation and pranayama.

Answer (score 0):

there is only one way. divert your attention to thinking about supreme consciousness. you have to be absorbed in either bhakti or studying about the supreme consciousness. once you start spending your time this way automatically you withdraw from worldly pleasures without effort because you will be self satisfied in devotion. this happiness or rather fulfilment is so great that you don't even have thoughts of lust and everything that signifies lust seems dry. remember it all happens automatically the moment you start absorbing yourself in trying to understand your true nature. this has been clarified in bhagavad gita. it has worked for me miraculously. i was addicted to porn and masterbation and I was under depression for 3 years. the moment i started doing what i told it all blew out like extinguished fire.

there is no other way than this.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! We insist on citing some sources while answering questions. Visit "Sources and Citations" section from [FAQ](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/277) to learn more