# why we can not control our mind even chanting the hare -krishna mantra or any other highly recommended mantra by spiritual guru?

Tags: krishna, mantras, gita

when u sexual desire/lust  maya attack you , u cannot control the sexual desire/lust  even chanting mantra like hare krishna maha mantra or gayatari mantra etc

why we can not control our mind even chanting the hare -krishna mantra or any other highly recommended mantra by spiritual guru  ?

what is use of this mantra  when it is not work practically ? why hare krishna mantra  suggested in gita for controlling the mind?

Comment: Well Rome wasn't built in a day! You can't just throw away seeds in the fields and expect to have rich crop, you have to till the soil, clear out weeds, level it etc etc before sowing seeds similarly just chanting mantra won't help you much, there are other things that needs to be followed before chanting mantras directly. I would suggest start with the first step of Ashtang Yog i.e yama (abstinences) & move on to niyama (observances), asana (postures), pranayama (breathing), pratyahara (withdrawal), dharana (concentration), dhyana (meditation) and samadhi (absorption).

Comment: Pretty much similar to your earlier question here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/42715/11875

Comment: Lust or any sense desire is part of Maya program and are in body via mind, but not the soul/self. Mantras and Bhakti are just a simple beginning and for giving a glimpse of complex spirituality, but the actual path involves renunciation, Ashtang Yoga and meditation. I have explained the metaphysics of Purusha-Prakriti i.e. masculine-feminine earlier also https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38232

Comment: @ManuKumar what happened to ur original ID ? The given  post seem that user ID deleted

Comment: Yes, I deleted account after 1.5 years of writing over 100 answers with 1000+ reputation, as I realized i have invested enough time in understanding Shastras and discussions with other Hindus. But crucial answers are published in my blog which are my realizations.

Comment: oks why u deleted? @ManuKumar last time  i was gaining some knowlege from ur  answer also

Comment: Only a real time guru can clear your doubts, not online. In reality the entire universe is knowledge and Guru. Just like five fingers in the hand are not equal, similarly same knowledge is grasped in different manner by different people.  Every thing has a purpose, nothing is random or an accident.

Comment: How can i find a real guru @ManuKumar

Comment: You can pray to God, if your prayer is serious enough, you will find a guru. Or you can also visit any Shankara Ashram or Gaudiya Mattha to find Swami or monk and take initiation with a mantra.

Comment: okss thanks u i will try @ManuKumar

Comment: How to overcome sexual desire? https://iskcondesiretree.com/profiles/blogs/how-to-overcome-sexual-desire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I have said in the comment above that Rome wasn't built in a day! You can't just throw away seeds in the fields and expect to have rich crop, you have to till the soil  properly, clear out weeds, level it, add manure etc etc before sowing seeds, even after that you have to take proper care of your crops! Similarly just chanting mantra won't help you much, there are other things that needs to be followed religiously before chanting mantras directly.

Mind is just like a child, you have to cajole it, pamper it, talk to it, listen to what it is saying before making it listen to what you want to say. Basically you have to de-condition your mind. Mind is similar to other organs of the body, it's not something that is against you, in fact it is a very potent instrument of your body once you get to know how to deal with it!

The first step to get rid of sexual/lustful thoughts would be to stay away from such activities for few days to start with. When I say activities I mean reading/viewing/discussing/visualizing such material. Gradually increase the duration, take small steps initially. This will help in boosting your will power. This is the first step of
[Ashtanga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashtanga_(eight_limbs_of_yoga)) (eight limbs of yoga) referred to as ***yama*** (abstinences). Strictly follow this routine for few weeks.

Now as far as chanting a mantra is concerned it should not be a parrot like act, it will not lead you anywhere! You have to chant the mantra with full concentration, mentally focusing on each and every word of the mantra while chanting it. But concentration can not be built over night, it's a long process. You first need to follow a routine for at-least 21 days before it becomes a habit and then move on to the next step. Just chant the mantra loudly (not too loud!) in a peaceful & secluded place with full concentration, start with 5-10 minutes daily and gradually increase the duration. Don't rush! After few day start chanting it mentally for mental mantra japa is highly recommended. You can read about it more [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22637/11875).

Hope this will help you in your spiritual journey!